# grep'ing the files output from a previous grep

Tags: linux, grep, pipe

I don't know if this is possible, or if grep is the wrong tool, or what, but what I want to do is this:

```
grep -rsI "some_string" *.c
```

Then pipe the **list of files** where were results were found into a second grep:

```
grep -rsI "second_string" <list of files from first grep>
```

I know I can pipe the exact lines to a second grep via:

```
grep -rsI "some_string" *.c | grep "second_string"
```

but that's **not** what I'm looking for, I don't want to just search the lines where previous hits were, but the entire file those lines were in. Is that even possible? Any ideas?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

```
grep -rsIl "some_string" *.c | xargs grep -sI "second_string"
```

Comment: got a good way to throw this into a bash shell? something like: `alias grep2='grep -rsIl $1 * | xargs grep $2'` but working?

Comment: `grep2() { grep -rsIl "$1" *.c | xargs grep "$2"; }`

Answer (score 5):

Use `-l` option to list files that match then `xargs` command to apply `grep` on those files.

```
grep -l -rsI "some_string" *.c | xargs grep "second_string"
```